# grep-like query for postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

With the `~` operator, it is simple to find all lines in a table for which a column matches a given regexp pattern :

```
SELECT description from book where description ~ 'hell?o'
matches lines containing hello or helo
```

Instead of the description, I would like to SELECT a snippet of text around each occurences of the pattern, so if a line contains

```
description = "aaaheloaaabbbhellobbbcccheloccc"
```

I would like 3 lines as output :

```
"aaaheloaaa"
"bbbhellobbb"
"cccheloccc"
```

which I call a "grep-like" query because it can show extracts of the column where the match is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT
  regexp_matches(description,'(.{0,3})('||'hell?o'||')(.{0,3})','g')
FROM
  book
WHERE description ~ 'hell?o'
```

Without the `WHERE` clause you will get `null` in rows, where were no matches for regexp.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `regexp_split_to_table` function:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

And you can use it like this:

```
SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', E'\\s+') AS foo;
```

The return:

```
  foo   
--------
 the    
 quick  
 brown  
 fox    
 jumped 
 over   
 the    
 lazy   
 dog    
(9 rows)
```

So in your case this would look like:

```
select res from book, regexp_split_to_table(book.description, E'...hell?o...') res;
```